# Removing Values from an Array using the Filter Method

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array and subsequent unknown number of arguments, how can I remove all elements from the initial array that are of the same value as these arguments? This is what I have so far:

```
function destroyer(arr) {
    var arrayOfArgs = [];
    var newArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        newArray = arr.filter(function (value) {
            return value !== arguments[i + 1];
        });
    }
    return newArray;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Comment: @nnnnnn No, it just returns the first argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with arrow function [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

[**Demo**](http://www.es6fiddle.net/imzuru3b/)

```
function destroyer(arr, ...remove) {
    return arr.filter(e => !remove.includes(e));
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

```js
function destroyer(arr, ...remove) {
    return arr.filter(e => !remove.includes(e));
}

var updatedArr = destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
console.log(updatedArr);
```

**Equivalent Code in ES5:**

```
function destroyer(arr) {
    var toRemove = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return arr.filter(function(e) {
        return toRemove.indexOf(e) === -1;
    });
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
    var toRemove = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return arr.filter(function (e) {
        return toRemove.indexOf(e) === -1;
    });
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to specify the subsequent arguments, [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to filter the `arr`, and [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to determine whether `args` contains specific item.

```
function destroyer(arr, ...args) {
  return arr.filter(x=> !args.includes(x))
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3))
```